Getting WARC files from archive.org
I'm using the interface at https://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx/ to find saved web pages on archive.org. The results returned by this interface can be used to build an URL for the interface: https://web.archive.org/web/YYYYMMDDhhmmssid_/http://domain/page which gets me a bare copy of the stored page. I would rather download a .warc.gz record of the page.
I understand that archive.org stores crawled pages in WARC format and, indeed, I can find some on the site - https://archive.org/details/1813843-20170423215801.warc.gz for example. But I can't find a path from a cdx search result to a WARC record.
